# Can we Insert multiple rows data using one single insert statement in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to insert data into table.

```
Insert into TEAMS (TEAM_CODE,TEAM_NAME,TEAM_DIVISION,TEAM_CITY,TEAM_STATE,TEAM_COACH,TEAM_STADIUM,TEAM_STAD_CAP)        
VALUES                    
('BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''),      
('BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''),      
('BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''),      
('BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''),      
('BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''),                    
('NEP','New England Patriots','AFC EAST','Foxboro','MA','Bill Belichek','Gillette Stadium','');
```

Can we Insert multiple data using one single command ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into TEAMS (TEAM_CODE,TEAM_NAME,TEAM_DIVISION,TEAM_CITY,TEAM_STATE,TEAM_COACH,TEAM_STADIUM,TEAM_STAD_CAP)
            select 'BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''
union select 'BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''
union select 'BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''
union select 'BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''
union select 'BUF','Buffalo bulls','AFC EAST','Buffalo','NY','Doug Marrone','Ralph Wilson Jr.Stadium',''
union select 'NEP','New England Patriots','AFC EAST','Foxboro','MA','Bill Belichek','Gillette Stadium','';
```

Comment: You can't just `SELECT` in Oracle. You need to select from something, eg `dual`

Comment: And while you are at it fix your `UNION SELECT`. Replace it with `UNION ALL SELECT`, otherwise the first five rows will be inserted as one